# OpenCV can't display image

Tags: qt, opencv, mingw

I am very new to OpenCV, but I am very keen to learn to use it - I have installed OpenCV 2.4.5 and using Qt 5.1.1-32 bit and MinGW (ver.4.8.0), pretty much following the steps in the online tutorial in youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ny34LpmWijo

I got the expected result from the tutorial. However when I tried the first simple snippet from the OpenCV 2 cookbook site ( http://www.laganiere.name/opencvCookbook/chap1s1_2.shtml ) to read and display image I kept getting this message:

```
"..OpenCv error: bad flag (parameter or structure field)(Unrecognized or unsupported array of type) in cvGetMat, file D:\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp,line2482

terminte called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
 what(): D:\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat..."
```

Initially I thought this is due to OS incompatibility (I run Windows Vista), but the same problem appears when I did similar things in Windows 7. Can anyone help? Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the application from **Qt Creator** and you are not giving `cv::imread()` the **full path** to the image, Qt Creator expects the image to be in the same folder as the binary executable.

My guess is that you are using a **relative path** to the image and the image is located in the same folder as the source code, hence the error.